# How to subtract one table column values to the other table column values

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have two tables Stock and Sale

Stock

```
id Name size Qty
1  box1  10  100
2  box2  12  200   
3  box3  14  500
4  box4  16  700
```

Sale

```
id Name size Qty
1  box1  10  1
2  box2  12  2  
3  box3  14  5
4  box4  16  7
```

I want this result after Subtract Qty

Stock

```
id Name size Qty
1  box1  10  99
2  box2  12  198  
3  box3  14  495
4  box4  16  693
```

Help!

Comment: What database are you using?   MySQL and SQLite are not the same thing.

Comment: mySql and SQLite both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can JOIN the tables by `id` and `name` then simply subtract the `Qty` values. Added [table alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) name for better readability

```
SELECT ST.id, ST.Name, ST.size, (ST.Qty - SA.Qty) AS Qty
FROM Stock ST
INNER JOIN Sale SA ON SA.id = ST.id AND SA.Name = ST.Name
```

If you though join by `Name` is not needed then you can join only by `id` as

```
SELECT ST.id, ST.Name, ST.size, (ST.Qty - SA.Qty) AS Qty
FROM Stock ST
INNER JOIN Sale SA ON SA.id = ST.id
```

---

**Update** for SQLite

```
UPDATE Stock 
SET Qty = ( SELECT ST.Qty - SA.Qty
            FROM Stock ST
            INNER JOIN Sale SA ON SA.id = ST.id )
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Stock )
```

Got reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29064919/2451726)

Answer (score 0):

If you want store the result In mysql you can (using the name for relation) update

```
update Stock as a
inner join Sale as b on a.name = b.name 
set a.Qty = a.Qty -b.Qty
```

or using id for relation

```
update Stock as a
inner join Sale as b on a.id = b.id 
set a.Qty = a.Qty -b.Qty
```

or if you simply want a select  you can

```
select a.id, a.name, a.size,  a.Qty -b.Qty as qty
from fromStock as a 
inner join Sale as b on a.id = b.id
```

In sqlite the update with inner join is not allowed so you use the subselect

```
update Stock 
set Qty = (    select Stock.Qty -Sale.Qty from Stock
                Inner join Sale on  Sale.name = Stock.name )
WHERE
EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    from Stock
                Inner join Sale on  Sale.name = Stock.name 
)
```

Comment: @10086  weel so .. you can easy get your result

Comment: how can i do in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Stock.id, Stock.Name, Stock.size, (Stock.Qty - Sale.Qty) AS Qty
FROM Stock
INNER JOIN Sale ON Sale.id = Stock.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
Select table.id,table.name,table.size,sum(table.qty) from
(Select id,name,size,qty from stock 
Union
Select id,name,size,qty*-1 from sale) as table group by table.id,table.name,table.size
```