# What is the correct SQL Syntax?

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite

I am struggling to resolve a SQL syntax problem in a Laravel Eloquent query. So I've gone right back to the root, and tried to get a query working in simple SQL. And I'm stumped. I'm no expert, but this is baffling me.

I've had a look at the [Update with Join in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite) post, but I think that one is more around the issue of joins.

I'm testing this on SQLLite, which surely is representative of SQL proper?

Two tables: Instructions and Knowns. I want to update one column in the Knowns from (the latest) Instructions. Get that right, and I can solve the rest myself (I hope!).

```
-- This works fine
Select instructions.rowid from instructions 
where instructions.EngagementTitle not null


-- This doesn't
UPDATE knowns 
SET    EngagementTitle = instructions.EngagementTitle
WHERE  id IN (
  SELECT knowns.id 
  FROM   knowns 
  INNER JOIN instructions 
  ON knowns.reference = instructions.reference
)
```

Error Message

```
no such column: instructions.EngagementTitle: 

UPDATE knowns 
SET    EngagementTitle = instructions.EngagementTitle 
WHERE  id IN (
  SELECT knowns.id 
  FROM   knowns 
  LEFT JOIN instructions 
  ON knowns.reference = instructions.reference
)
```

Both tables both have the column - triple checked.

```
`EngagementTitle` varchar NOT NULL
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need a `JOIN` if sqllite supports `update from join`

Comment: Outside of your sub-query, `instructions` is not defined. I think you're looking for an `UPDATE` with joins but I'm not sure if SQLite supports the syntax like MySQL does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update with Join in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite)

Comment: I think the fosus of that one is about the specifics of a JOIN relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE knowns 
SET    EngagementTitle = instructions.EngagementTitle 
...
```

The `instructions` table isn't "known" here, only `knowns`. The scope of the table expressions is "downwards" only. You can use a table introduced in a superquery in a subquery but not the other way round.

Try using subselects:

```
UPDATE knowns
       SET engagementtitle = (SELECT instructions.engagementtitle
                                     FROM instructions
                                     WHERE instructions.reference = knowns.reference)
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM instructions 
                            WHERE instructions.reference = knowns.reference);
```

I also replaced your `WHERE` with an `EXISTS`. I guess that is how you actually wanted it. It will only update rows from `knowns` where an entry exists in `instructions` for. The way you did it, with a `LEFT JOIN` in the subquery to `IN`, you'd just updated all rows, as a `LEFT JOIN` includes all rows from the left table, thus all IDs from `knowns` are in the result (You maybe wanted an `INNER JOIN`, that would have worked.).

But note, there must no more than one entry in `instructions` for one row in `knowns` for this to work. I silently assumed that this is the case.

Comment: Thank you, seriously.. this has been bugging me no end, and I had wondered about that whole "downwards" thing although you expressed better than I could have. And yes, the one instruction = one known is correct.Much appreciated.