# can't calculate a mean that excludes the current observation using .each block and sqlite3

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, calculated-columns

I've done my best to strip down code to bare minimum and provided concise explanation of problem (I hope)

I have a db scheme as indicated below.

```
def a_method(info_hash)
     ...
     db.execute2 "create table if not exists Table1(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Item TEXT, Amount FLOAT, Type TEXT, AvgInc FLOAT, AvgX FLOAT, Total FLOAT)"
     ...
end
```

This creates my schema.  Once I populate the database, I run the following method which gives me the `#{@total}` value grouped by my `Type` column:

```
def get_total(info_hash)
    ...
    get_amt =  db.execute2 "SELECT sum(Amount) from Table1 WHERE Type = :Type", info_hash[:category]
    puts "foo"
    db.execute2 "UPDATE Table1 SET Total = :Total WHERE Type = :Type", get_amt[1][0], info_hash[:category]
    @total=get_amt[1][0]
    ...
    @total
end
```

I want to run the following method to compute an `Item` average in the event the item did not exist.  Basically the impact each `Item` has on the `Type` average.

**Please see the in code comment for where I think my logic is faulty**

```
def method_excluding(info_hash) 
     ...
     get_num =  db.execute2 "SELECT Amount from Table1 WHERE Type = :Type", info_hash[:category]
    i = 0
    get_num.each do |item| 
    #purpose of block to compute an average value for Type as if #{item} did not exist.  So: the average value for Type EXLCUDING #{item}
        if i == 1
            @avgx = (@total - get_num[1][0]) / i
        elsif i > 1
            @avgx = (@total - get_num[i][0]) / (i - 1)
        end         
        i+=1
        db.execute2 "UPDATE Table1 SET AvgX = :AvgX WHERE Type = :Type", @avgx, info_hash[:category]
        ...
end
```

**Please advise on how I can get to my desired outcome.**

Comment: Instead of doing two queries in your `get_total`, which is subject to [Race Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), do one with an `UPDATE` [using a `JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite). An atomic update won't expose you to situations where the total computes incorrectly.

Comment: If you want a counter, consider `get_num.each_with_index do |item, i|` where `i` is a 0-indexed counter provided automatically. There's no need for a separate test. Also **`i=1` is an assignment, not a comparison**. For that you need `==`. It's worth noting that your first iteration will not match either `if` branch when `i == 0`.

Comment: @tadman it's not that I WANT a counter...I need to know the total `Type` I have to compute an average.  How can I do this w/o the counter?

Comment: @tadman can u show me an example of `join`.  Reading up now, I don't think it pertains for this specific use case...`join` essentially is used when having 2 different tables, not 1.  Also, can there be situations where `total` computes incorrectly?

Comment: `JOIN` is precisely what you use when you have two different tables. It's how you relate them together in a single query.

Comment: @tadman yes. but I only have myTable...and column for `total`

Comment: The name `myTable` is really annoyingly vague here, and it's not clear why you're calling `SUM(Amount)` on a table and then updating the table with that sum. Won't that increment infinitely, as the future sum is now higher? A slightly more concrete use case would help considerably here.

Comment: Every time you update your table with a new value it updates *every* matching row. Do you really want to do that? And why save these values at all? It's trivial to compute them on the fly when needed...

Comment: @tadman apologies renamed table for clarification. Pls understand `@total` will populate its own column.  So it won't increment infinitely...

Comment: @Shawn it's more to have `@total` always on hand...user is able to display each row...so they can see what the total is as well.

Comment: `myTable` and `table1` are two flavours of the same. Is this a transactions table? A balances table? What's going on in there? You sum all amounts for a single category, then *update all entries in the database for that category* with that total. If there's two or more rows per category, this keeps incrementing forever. If there's one row per category then you don't need `SUM()`.

Comment: @tadman i see now.  noob @ sqlite3.  I **thought** `sum()` summed up entire columns - and `insert` that summation into `Total`. This is a **category balances** tale (it sums up categories of amounts of things)

Comment: `SUM()` will tally up all values in that column for all records matching the `WHERE` conditions, if any, or all records otherwise. I'm still not sure that this is the structure you want. Normally you sum from one table to another related, but different table, and do that with a `SUM(Amount) GROUP BY Type` to get aggregate sums per-type.

Comment: Oh, I think there's an error in how you compute average - you're calculating the total - current row value divided by the number of rows seen so far minus 1, not the number of total rows minus 1. That doesn't sound right. (Side note: Once sqlite 3.28 is out (Currently available for beta testing), you can calculate the average of all but the current row with `SELECT Amount, avg(Amount) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS AvgX FROM Table1 WHERE Type = :Type`)

Comment: @Shawn that **is** a good observation!  I have some work with this obviously.